90's/2000's movie involving an Asian guy/hitman/assassin/ronin wielding a Katana
US movie. English. Either a theatrical movie or a made for TV/DVD movie.
The Asian guy, as mentioned in the title, wields a Katana, and wears a long black trench-coat. Two other protagonists are a man and woman.
The villains include a lab-coat wearing villain (I think he's the main baddie) and a tall, large, thickish and very burly looking henchman (who is bald/shaven head). 
The story setting is set in the US, because I remember nearly every other character being Caucasian.
Story Points

One scene has the Asian guy attacking a target (who is with his family I think). He slices the targets throat and he jumps out the window. He meets with the woman protagonist and he states that he's a killer.
Another scene has the villains in a dark complex. I think the lab coat villain is trying to create genetically enhanced soldiers, as the scene has a child face off against the burly henchman and does very well.
Another scene has the Asian guy and two of the protagonists attacked by one of the enhanced humans, who is shown to be superior in combat. I think what happens next are the protagonists driving in a car in an attempt to escape this enhanced human, and I think he uses his enhanced speed to catch up with them. What happens next, I can't remember
The climax has the Asian guy fighting the burly henchman, and the burly henchman has the advantage and is winning. The burly henchman locks the Asian guy in a deadly bear hug. Knowing he doesn't have any options left, the Asian guy impales himself with his katana, and also impales the burly henchman, and they both bleed to death.
The lab coat villain then appears and attempts to kill the two remaining protagonists, but the male protagonist gets hold of a gun and shoots the lab coat villain.


Because you said male, it must not be Kill Bill, but that's what came to mind.

And this is How "identify-this-movie" tagged questions should looks like. kudos for good question

"The story setting is set in the US, because I remember nearly every other character being Caucasian." As a European, I wonder if I should be offended ;) Especially given the meaning of the word Caucasian: white-skinned; of European origin. (and its origins, as the Caucasus is a European mountain chain, though somewhat shared with Asia)

I don't think I actually saw these movies, but their main characters seem to fit your description so maybe you should check them out:

Versus (2000)
Crying Freeman (1995)


Sadly not the movie I'm looking for :( But thank you very much for trying to help :)

The film is definitely not Versus but to anyone who hasn't seen it: you're missing out!
